# JAVA_HOME variable in windows

Tags: java-home

In CMD `echo %JAVA_HOME%` displays Java directory, does this work the same on unix.
I have tried `echo $JAVA_HOME`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it "works the same". The difference here is the way in which you're referencing envirnment variables. In linux you should use `$variable` notation.

So in this case `echo $JAVA_HOME` shows value of `JAVA_HOME` environment variable, or nothing if it wasn't set.

`echo JAVA_HOME` outputs just a string `JAVA_HOME`

To set environment variable you should use `export JAVA_HOME=something`. If you'd like to have this saved between restarts you could add such line to `~/.bashrc` file.

Answer (score 1):

Type in terminal 
`echo $JAVA_HOME`.
If nothing appears, set it with this command

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64
```

This will differ according to your JDK type & version.